# How to add rows to flex-box table?

Tags: html, flexbox

I did flex-box table. It's placed here https://jsfiddle.net/p7g1n4d8/2/
The problem that I can't understand how to add rows to it, to make it's looks like:
[image]

```
        <div class="TableContainer">
                <div class="col-1">
                <div class="col-1-header">№</div>
        </div>

            <div class="col-1">
                <div class="col-1-header">Frutes</div>
                <div class="col-1-nested">
                    <div class="col-2-container">
                        <div class="col-2-header">№</div>
                        <div>1</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2-container">
                        <div class="col-2-header">Date</div>
                        <div>2</div>
                    </div>                  
                </div>

            </div>
</div>
```

If I am adding more div's I am getting something like: [image]

Comment: Just add more `div`s with numbers? But… why not just use an actual `<table>` for tabular data?

Comment: @helb I added example what's to happen with more div's

Comment: your main table container has the flex direction of row so adding new divs will spoil your table. check this.. its not exactly what you want but similar ..  https://jsfiddle.net/supercoder123/p7g1n4d8/31/

Answer (score 0):

## There you go! :)

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.TableContainer {
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  /*flex-grow: 3;*/
}

#flexBox {
  display: flex;
  border: none;
}

.col-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col-1-nested {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.col-2-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.col-1-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.col-2-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.rowtable {
  display: flex;
  border: none;
}

.rows {
  padding: 7px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="TableContainer">

  <div id="flexBox">
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="col-1-header">№</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="col-1-header">Frutes</div>
      <div class="col-1-nested">
        <div class="col-2-container">
          <div class="col-2-header">№</div>
          <div>1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2-container">
          <div class="col-2-header">Date</div>
          <div>2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="rowtable">
    <div class="rows">1</div>
    <div class="rows">2</div>
    <div class="rows">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowtable">
    <div class="rows">1</div>
    <div class="rows">2</div>
    <div class="rows">3</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Check [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) out.